# Responsive Layout Issues - ONLY present on iPad. Unsure how to resolve

Tags: javascript, ipad, responsive-design

I'm having a few problems with my portfolio - if/when viewed on an iPad in vertical orientation, scrolling down seems to pull you back to the top. I'm not entirely sure if this is a css/js issue, or something else entirely. Resizing the browser on my computer to the same dimensions doesn't appear to replicate the problem so.. at a bit of a loss.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Problem site in question:

http://alexandermasters.com/portfolio/weddings/20110827

This is an edited version of the theme template (template was designed strictly to scroll horizontally) but on the pages with the template untouched (http://alexandermasters.com/portfolio/travel/20100928) the issue persists.

Suggestions?

Edit: the offending code (within main.js) is below:

```
;(function ($, window, $window, $document, isUndefined) {

    $(function () {

        var $html       = $('html'),
            $main       = $('#main'),
            $header     = $('#header'),
            $footer     = $('#footer'),

            // Components
            $sidebar             = $('.sidebar'),
            $keyRight            = $('#key-right'),
            $keyLeft             = $('#key-left'),
            $navTip              = $('.nav-tip'),
            $scrollContainer     = $('.scroll-container'),
            mobileNav,

            // Functions
            getHorizontalPageHeight,
            pageResizer,

            // Gloal variables
            allowUpscale = $html.is('.upscale');

        if (iPadWithIOS4()) {
            $html.addClass('ipad-ios4');
        }

        getHorizontalPageHeight = function () {
            return $window.height() - $header.outerHeight() - $footer.outerHeight();
        };

        /**
         * Fixes iOS 7.0~7.0.2 Safari bug. Safari reports $window.height() to be 692, which is not correct.
         * Also there's a permanent scrollbar which allows users to scroll 20px, to prevent that we just scroll back to the
         * top. This is only required in landscape mode.
         */
        if (!!navigator.platform.match(/iPad/) && $html.is('.horizontal-page')) {
            var _getHorizontalPageHeight = getHorizontalPageHeight,
                IOS7PreventVerticalScroll = function () {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
                        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
                    }
                };

            getHorizontalPageHeight = function () {
                if ($window.height() == 692) {
                    return window.innerHeight - $header.outerHeight() - $footer.outerHeight();
                }
                return _getHorizontalPageHeight();
            };

            $document.on('scroll', _.debounce(IOS7PreventVerticalScroll, 100));
            $window.on('orientationchange.ios7-safari-bug.fluxus', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if ($window.height() == 692) {
                        IOS7PreventVerticalScroll();
                    }
                }, 200);
            });
        }

        $('.horizontal-page').each(function () {

            var resizer = function () {

                var windowWidth = $window.width(),
                    windowHeight = $window.height(),
                    // The header is position:fixed we have to calculate the offset for main page dynamically.
                    headerHeight = $header.outerHeight();
                    footerHeight = $footer.outerHeight();

                // If we are on a small screen
                if (windowWidth <= 480) {

                    if ($html.is('.no-scroll')) {
                        $main.css({
                            height: windowHeight - headerHeight,
                            top: 0
                        });
                    } else {
                        $main.css({
                            height: 'auto',
                            top: 0
                        });
                    }

                } else {

                    $main.css({
                        height: getHorizontalPageHeight(),
                        top: headerHeight
                    });

                }

            };

            $window.on('resize.horizontal-page.fluxus', _.debounce(resizer));
            resizer();

            $window.on('orientationchange.horizontal-page.fluxus', function () {
                setTimeout(resizer, 10);
            });

            $main.transition({
                opacity: 1
            }, 100);

        });

        /**
         * General size adjustments on window resize.
         */
        pageResizer = function () {

            /**
             * Update tinyscrollbar values.
             */
            $scrollContainer.each(function () {
                var $t = $(this),
                    tsb = $t.data('tsb');

                $t.find('.scrollbar, .track').css('height', $t.height());
                tsb && tsb.update();
            });


            if ($window.width() <= 768) {

                // Initialize mobile menu only if we have a small sceen size.
                if (!mobileNav) {

                    // Make mobile menu item array.
                    var $siteNavigation = $('.site-navigation'),
                        $mobileNavItems = $siteNavigation.find('a').filter(function () {

                            var $t = $(this),
                                level = $t.parents('ul').length;

                            $t.data('level', level);

                            if (level == 1) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                if ($t.closest('.current-menu-item, .current_page_ancestor').length) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            return false;

                        });

                    /**
                     * Initialize mobile menu.
                     */
                    mobileNav = new MobileNav($mobileNavItems, {
                        openButtonTitle: $siteNavigation.data('menu'),
                        active: $siteNavigation.find('.current-menu-item > a')
                    });

                }

            }

            /**
             * Trigger vertical center plugin.
             */
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.js-vertical-center').verticalCenter();
            }, 100);

        };

        $window.on('resize.page-resizer.fluxus', _.debounce(pageResizer));
        pageResizer();

        /**
         * Arrows and mousewheel navigation plugin.
         */
        globalNav = new Navigation({
            onSetItems: function () {
                this.$items.length && $navTip.show();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Full page slider
         */
        $('.slider').each(function () {

            var $slider = $(this),
                slider;

            $slider.fluxusSlider({
                    onNextSlide: function () {
                        globalNav.options.onNextItem();
                    },
                    onPreviousSlide: function () {
                        globalNav.options.onPreviousItem();
                    }
                });

            slider = $slider.data('slider');

            slider.slideCount > 1 && $navTip.show();

            globalNav.disableKeyboard();

            $keyRight.click(function (e) {
                slider.next();
                e && e.preventDefault();
            });

            $keyLeft.click(function (e) {
                slider.previous();
                e && e.preventDefault();
            });

        });


        /**
         * Appreciate plugin
         */
        var $appreciate = $('.btn-appreciate');
        $appreciate.appreciate();


        /**
         * Sharrre plugin
         */
        $('#sharrre-footer').each(function () {

            var $el = $(this),
                services = {},
                buttonsTitle = $el.data('buttons-title');

            if (!$el.data('services')) {
                return;
            }

            // retrieve social networks from DOM element.
            $.each($el.data('services').split(','), function () {
                services[this] = true;
            });

            $el.sharrre({
                share: services,
                buttonsTemplate: buttonsTitle ? '<b>' + buttonsTitle + '<a href="#" class="close"></a></b>' : '',
                urlCurl: $el.data('curl'),
                template: '<b class="share">{title}</b>' +
                          '<span class="counts">' +
                            (services.facebook ? '<b class="count-facebook">{facebook}</b>' : '') +
                            (services.twitter ?'<b class="count-twitter">{twitter}</b>' : '') +
                            (services.googlePlus ?'<b class="count-plus">{plus}</b>' : '') +
                          '</span>',
                render: function(self, options) {
                    var html = this.template.replace('{title}', options.title);
                    html = html.replace('{facebook}', options.count.facebook);
                    html = html.replace('{twitter}', options.count.twitter);
                    html = html.replace('{plus}', options.count.googlePlus);
                    $(self.element).html(html);
                    $el.show();
                }
            });

        });

        $('#sharrre-project').each(function () {

            var $el = $(this),
                services = {},
                buttonsTitle = $el.data('buttons-title');

            if (!$el.data('services')) {
                return;
            }

            // retrieve social networks from DOM element.
            $.each($el.data('services').split(','), function () {
                services[this] = true;
            });

            $el.sharrre({
                share: services,
                buttonsTemplate: buttonsTitle ? '<div class="arrow"></div><b>' + buttonsTitle + '<a href="#" class="close"></a></b>' : '',
                urlCurl: $el.data('curl'),
                template: '<span class="icon"></span><div class="box">' +
                            '<a class="share" href="#">{title}</a>' +
                            '<b class="count-total">{total}</b>' +
                          '</div>',
                render: function(self, options) {
                    var total = options.shorterTotal ? self.shorterTotal(options.total) : options.total,
                        html = this.template.replace('{title}', options.title).replace('{total}', total);
                    $(self.element).html(html);
                    $el.css('display', 'inline-block');
                },
                afterLoadButtons: function () {
                    var index = 0,
                        $buttons = this.$el.find('.button'),
                        count = $buttons.each( function () {
                                    index++;
                                    $(this).addClass('button-' + index);
                                }).length;
                    this.$el.addClass('social-services-' + count);
                }
            });

        });



        /**
         * Fixes menu issue, when popup is outside the screen.
         */
        $('.site-navigation .has-children').hover(function () {

            var $submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
            if ($submenu.length) {

                // if popup is outside the screen, then align it by the right side of the screen.
                if ($submenu.offset().left + $submenu.outerWidth() - $(document).scrollLeft() > $window.width()) {
                    $submenu.addClass('sub-menu-right');
                }

            }

        }, function () {

            $(this).children('.sub-menu').removeClass('sub-menu-right');

        });


        /**
         * If our page has a horizontal layout.
         */
        if ($html.is('.horizontal-page')) {

            /**
             * Enable tinyscrollbar plugin.
             */
            $scrollContainer.tinyscrollbar({
                axis: 'y'
            });

            /**
             * Enable keyboard navigation.
             */
            globalNav.options.onNextItem = function () {
                $keyRight.addClass('flash');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $keyRight.removeClass('flash');
                }, 200);
            };

            globalNav.options.onPreviousItem = function () {
                $keyLeft.addClass('flash');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $keyLeft.removeClass('flash');
                }, 200);
            };

            $keyRight.click(function (e) {
                globalNav.nextItem();
                e && e.preventDefault();
            });

            $keyLeft.click(function (e) {
                globalNav.previousItem();
                e && e.preventDefault();
            });

        }
```

Comment: You can rule out CSS/JS by disabling/not including them.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I don't see have any scrolling issues on my iPod 5 using Chrome or Safari. There are two small horizontal bars near the top of the page that look out of place. With so many images, maybe the page was still loading?

Comment: Issue only appears to be present on iPads.

Answer (score 0):

According to Intheme, the author of the Fluxus Template, the following fix has been released that should solve the issue.

By modifying the following line of code in js/main.js

```
if (!!navigator.platform.match(/iPad/)) {
```

to this

```
if (!!navigator.platform.match(/iPad/) && $html.is('.horizontal-page')) {
```

Comment: According to my main.js file, the fix is already in there:

"Fixes iOS 7.0~7.0.2 Safari bug. Safari reports $window.height() to be 692, which is not correct. Also there's a permanent scrollbar which allows users to scroll 20px, to prevent that we just scroll back to the top. This is only required in landscape mode."

I suspect this has something to do with me modifying the template to have a certain portfolio as 'always' vertical?

Comment: Just tried both portfolios (original and personal modification) in vertical. It seems to snap back when the menu disappears off the screen :(